# Subset data by Year from period column

Tags: r

I have data with month and year column, how can I subset this to be per year along, here is sample dataset

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Data
df <- data.frame("Hospital" = c("Buge Hospital", "Buge Hospital", "Greta Hospital", "Greta Hospital",
                                "Makor Hospital", "Makor Hospital"),
                 "Period" = c("Jul-18","Aug-18", "Jul-19","Aug-19", "Jul-20","Aug-20"),
                 "Medical admissions" = c(12,56,0,40,5,56),
                 "Surgical admissions" = c(10,2,0,50,20,56),
                 "Inpatient admissions" = c(9,5,6,0,60,96))
```

I have tried this but I get empty dataset

```
data_18 <- subset(df, format(as.Date(df$Period, format="%b/%Y"),"%Y")== 2018)
```

I want to pull out monthly data for each year so that  so that I can observe data trends for that monthly period
Expected result is to subset and get only data for each year individually example is like pull out monthly data for 2018.

Comment: Can you say what analysis you want to carry out on the sub data? what do you want the final output to look like?

Comment: @Peter I want to pull out monthly data for each year so that  so that I can observe data trends for that monthly period

Comment: Use `separate(df, Period, c("Month", "Year"))` from `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: @Bappa Das How about getting for a single year like 2018

Comment: Use `df %>% separate(Period, c("Month", "Year")) %>% filter(Year == 18)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
data <- Filter(nrow,split(df,list(gsub(".*-","",df$Period),df$Hospital)))
data_18 <- data[grepl("^18",names(data))]
```

which gives

```
> data
$`18.Buge Hospital`
       Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions Inpatient.admissions
1 Buge Hospital Jul-18                 12                  10                    9
2 Buge Hospital Aug-18                 56                   2                    5

$`19.Greta Hospital`
        Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions Inpatient.admissions
3 Greta Hospital Jul-19                  0                   0                    6
4 Greta Hospital Aug-19                 40                  50                    0

$`20.Makor Hospital`
        Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions Inpatient.admissions
5 Makor Hospital Jul-20                  5                  20                   60
6 Makor Hospital Aug-20                 56                  56                   96
```

and

```
> data_18
$`18.Buge Hospital`
       Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions Inpatient.admissions
1 Buge Hospital Jul-18                 12                  10                    9
2 Buge Hospital Aug-18                 56                   2
```

---

**EDIT**

If you just want to subset data in 2018 (thanks to @G. Grothendieck )

```
data_18 <- subset(df, grepl("18", Period))
```

Comment: Could you remove that  ```$`18.Buge Hospital'``` so that  it can just save  list of dataframes because we already have hospital column which I can easily Identify what hospital it is. I can loop through the list of dataframes and plot

Comment: @LivingstoneM Try `data_18 <- data[[grep("^18",names(data))]]`

Comment: ```recursive indexing failed at level 3``` is the error I get

Comment: @LivingstoneM I used the dataframe from you post and the codes worked well...did you use any other dataframe?

Comment: It would be sufficient to write this as: `subset(df, grepl("18", Period))`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you were trying for is :

```
subset(df, format(as.Date(paste('1', Period), '%d %b-%y'), "%Y") == 2018)

#       Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions Inpatient.admissions
#1 Buge Hospital Jul-18                 12                  10                    9
#2 Buge Hospital Aug-18                 56                   2                    5
```

Or using zoo's `yearmon`.

```
library(zoo)

subset(df, floor(as.yearmon(Period, "%b-%y")) == 2018)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, for example with `strsplit` or with tidyverse as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% separate(Period, into=c("Month", "Year"), "-") %>% filter(Year == 18)
```

and if you want to summarize, plot or something, use `group_by` instead of `filter`, for example:

```
df %>% 
  separate(Period, into=c("Month", "Year"), "-") %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarize(sum(Medical.admissions))
```

Comment: ... and without tidyverse: `subset(df, sub("^.*-", "", as.character(df$Period)) == 18)`

Answer (score 1):

And for a more pedestrian approach in response to your desire to subset on both year and month, and to reflect how the approach in your own code could be made to work:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)

# Data
df <- data.frame("Hospital" = c("Buge Hospital", "Buge Hospital", "Greta Hospital", "Greta Hospital",
                                "Makor Hospital", "Makor Hospital"),
                 "Period" = c("Jul-18","Aug-18", "Jul-19","Aug-19", "Jul-20","Aug-20"),
                 "Medical admissions" = c(12,56,0,40,5,56),
                 "Surgical admissions" = c(10,2,0,50,20,56),
                 "Inpatient admissions" = c(9,5,6,0,60,96),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# data wrangle to give you a valid date and year varibles, subsetting on year should be straightforward using dplyr::group_by(year, month)
df1 <-  
  df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0("01-", Period),format = "%d-%b-%y"),
         year = year(date),
         month = month(date))
```